# PHP Add Double quote to beginning and end of mysql table string field

Tags: php, mysql, replace

mysql table = products

field = category (string)

How to add double quotes at the beginning and end of the field when the string contains a comma?

current php code:

```php
$sql = "update products set category = replace(replace(replace(category,'&#34;','\"'),'&#62;','>'),'&#38;','&')";
```

Comment: your problem isn't clear enough but try this

$sql = "update products set category = \" replace(replace(replace(category,'"','"'),'>','>'),'&','&') \" ";

Comment: Why don't you use prepare statements?

Comment: @pLe0mAx. I am not a programmer so cannot answer that.

Comment: @lhbib hbart 3 The code I have included is not directly connected to my question but I included it to show what was currently in my script

Answer (score 0):

See the query below :

```
UPDATE products SET category = QUOTE(category);
```

Working at my end ..
I hope it will at your end too.

Comment: Hi. Will that work only for strings which include a comma, which is what I need, or for all strings?

Comment: The field is used for output to a csv file. Hence the need to double-quote strings which contain a comma (else the string splits because of the csv being comma-delimited).

Comment: This query will not work for comma delimit data. This will append quote to data exist in column. If you have some comma and other special character, then this query will count it a complete data and add quote in start and end of data. can you please add a picture or text of your data so that i can modify the query as per your need.

Comment: @ ARVIND IT The strings are actually Google Shopping Categories. An example is: "Home & Garden > Decor > Artwork > Posters, Prints, & Visual Artwork"
I need to remember to put double quotes around them for when they are output as a column in my csv. Thanks

Comment: Is anyone able to assist with this?